# How can I send more information via GET method? in VALENCE

Tags: get, valence

i need help with Valence portal.

I open the app with direct link
here:

```
http://192.168.1.1:7040?display=desktop&app=1001
```

but I need more data on this, PE: 'CODUSER' but if I put &coduser=1 doesn't work

```
http://192.168.1.1:7040?display=desktop&app=1001&coduser=1
```

I extecute an alert and this is the result to read the URL:

```
http://192.168.1.1:7040/desktop/examples/P01/index.html?app=1001&key=xxxxxxx&lang=en
```

URL doesn't contains the "coduser".

How can I send more information via GET method?

Thanks, Ivan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem. Not is the best solution but is an aceptable solution, if any knows other, tell me, please.

My Solution:
I created a new Hook.js. on this file can read a current url (here read all url, 'coduser' included).

on the new Hook:

```
cod=foundParameterURL('codUser');//personal function, include current URL (location.href)
Ext.util.Cookies.set("coduser",cod);
```

later on the app, read the Cookie:

```
var cod = Ext.util.Cookies.get("coduser");
```

and continue with normality

If any knows as send information Hook.js to app tell me please.

thanks for all, Ivan.